# Select dropdown appears small and off center

Tags: google-chrome, ui, css

Has anyone experienced this before?

Chrome on Macbook and my dropdown options are appearing like the image below. I've been trying to track down the issue, if it's css or a user preference on the mac.

I've tried changing the resolution, changing some system settings, and having no luck with it.

Specs:

Macbook: Macbook Pro

Software: macOS Monterey version 12.5.1

Chrome: Version 105.0.5195.125

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted?

Comment: @benwiggy I have and still experience the issue.

Comment: Try testing a different browser, and check on a Chrome users' forum to see if it's a Chrome issue.